# Windows.Forms extended desktop, detect individual screens in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-capture, multiple-monitors

I am currently working on an application in C# where it will be important to be able to "catch" all screens attatched to the computer it is running on. However there is an issue using Windows.Forms that I can not seem to get past.

Basically, from the API and everything else I've read you would use AllScreens[i] to access all the screens attached to the system. 
The issue however is that when I have two screens attached to the computer in extended desktop, it detects it as one screen.
As an example, if I run:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Width
```

I would expect to get the width of the first screen in the array but instead I get the combined width of both screens.

In fact when running: 
`AllScreens.Length` it returns 1.

Is there a way to actually detect individual screens using Windows.Forms?

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is get all the information of the screens bij using this code:

```
string info = "";
foreach (var screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
            {
                info = info + "Working Area: " + screen.WorkingArea.ToString() + " Primary Screen:" + screen.Primary.ToString() + "\n";
            }
```

This code gives all the screens indivudual with their working area.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can you take a look for extra info.

Comment: Tried this right now with two screens plugged in, still not able to actually get both screens reported. The output still only prints "one" screen, however it now reports the width of that screen correctly instead of doing the combined width of both screens as I got before.
I added a quick integer just to keep track of how many times it goes through the foreach loop and I still only get one.

Comment: That's odd, I've tested this code and get three screens in return (because my setup uses three screens). If you use screen.DeviceName.ToString() it should show DISPLAY1, DISPLAY2. Can you try this in a new project, just to be sure it isn't a bug in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but here is what you can use to get the working area of screen

```
  System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Width
```

Where AllScreens is the collection of screens available.

Comment: This works in order to get the correct width of screen number "0", which is a lot better than using Bounds.Width which reports the combined width of all screens. However, it does not completely solve the problem since I can't use AllScreens[1] for example to get the next screen. Two screens in extended desktop mode still reports as a single screen.

Comment: The AllScreens will show the monitors that appears in the control panel of windows. For instance if you have an Eyefinity set up as a single large surface (SLS), it will appear as a single item in AllScreens or if you have it set up as 3 separate monitors then it will be 3 items in AllScreens. You might have to look at the current settings of your machine.